# How to extract the matched string between two different characters?

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I've a record format of

```
"Bum Reviews" (2008) {The Dark Knight Rises (#5.9)} 2012
```

I need to extract the move name, between `{` and `(`

I ended up doing

```
cat file | awk -F"{" '{print $2}' | awk -F"(" '{print $1}'
```

I want to know the best way using `perl`/`awk` regex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk -F"[{(]" '{print $3}' file
The Dark Knight Rises
```

To get it more exact, use:

```
awk -F"[{}]" '{split($2,a," [(]");print a[1]}' file
The Dark Knight Rises
```

Or

```
awk -F"[{}]" '{sub(/ \(.*/,"",$2);print $2}' file
The Dark Knight Rises
```

The two later will get only data between `{}` and then remove the `(..)`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `grep` with `-o` and `-P` options (using look-behind assertions).

```
grep -oP '(?<={)[^(]+' file
```

#### Example:

```
$ echo '"Bum Reviews" (2008) {The Dark Knight Rises (#5.9)} 2012' | grep -oP '(?<={)[^(]+'
The Dark Knight Rises
```

or `perl` if you insist:

```
echo '"Bum Reviews" (2008) {The Dark Knight Rises (#5.9)} 2012' | perl -lne '{ print /(?<={)[^(]+/g}'
```

Answer (score -1):

The regular expression

```
/ \{ \s* ( [^(){}\s] (?: [^(){}]* [^(){}\s] )? ) /x
```

will extract your title for you, as well as removing any leading or trailing white space. It also takes account of the case where there is no score in parentheses after the title.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = '"Bum Reviews" (2008) {The Dark Knight Rises (#5.9)} 2012';

my $title;
if ($s =~ / \{ \s* ( [^(){}\s] (?: [^(){}]* [^(){}\s] )? ) /x) {
  $title = $1;
  print qq{"$title"\n};
}
```

**output**

```
"The Dark Knight Rises"
```